# Ubuntu 14.04 boot hangs at "EXT4-fs: mounted filesystem without journal"

Tags: boot, 14.04, server

I have just made a new Ubuntu 14.04 installation on a new SSD Drive for my server.
Previously I had a Ubuntu 12.04 installation that worked fine, but I have now changed harddrive to an SSD.
The installation process completes without any problem. I do a manual partitioning with one boot partition (100Mb), one swap (2Gb) and the rest (ca. 60 Gb) for root partition.

When the system then boots it goes normal for some time and then stops at the point showed i picture:

(EXT4-fs (sdg1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)).

[Ubuntu 14.04 - Boot log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzi3r.jpg)

What can I do to fix it? What is wrong? Why does it not boot?

Comment: Maybe it can't access your filesystem?

Comment: Well all it has to access is what was written during installation and that went though without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. What I found was the server was actually coming up. I could ssh to it and found the issue is caused by the graphic Nvidia card.

I did:

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates-dev

And this did it. You might give it a try.